# Typical resistances of jumper wire and silver foil

Tags: resistance, conductivity, conductors

What is the typical resistances of the following or how can I go about calculating this approximately?

1) Typical jumper wires used in prototyping with breadboards
2) a silver foil with dimensions length:5cm, width:1cm

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivities_of_the_elements_(data_page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivities_of_the_elements_(data_page)) any use?

Comment: For jumper wires (usually around 22 to 24 AWG) see http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Comment: Online calculator for round wire [here](http://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-resistance-calculator.htm)

Comment: The 20cm jumper wire from a cheap Chinese supplier I have here have a total resistance (including contact resistance) of around 0.5 Ohm (not mOhm) and are 30 AWG.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, the resistance is in the order of 1-10 Ohm.

However, it heavily depends on the dimensions of the conductor. 10x longer jumper cables also have 10x the resistance.

Calculate it yourself:

$$R=\rho\cdot\frac{l}{A}$$

where \$A\$ is the cross section and \$l\$ the length of the conductor. \$\rho\$ is the specific resistance, see for example [wikipedia for a table of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials)

I'm not sure what you mean by silver foil, but if you mean the aluminum foil used in the kitchen, it has a typical thickness of 13µm, the thicker version 18µm. So, with \$A=0.01m\cdot 13\cdot10^{-6}m=130\cdot 10^{-9}m^2\$; \$\rho=2.82\cdot10^{-8}\Omega/m\$:

$$R=2.82\cdot10^{-8}\Omega/m\cdot\frac{0.05m}{130\cdot 10^{-9}m^2}=10.8m\Omega$$

But keep in mind that the surface of aluminum has a low conductivity, and when the current enters the foil through a small surface (like you connect a crocodile clip), the real resistance can be much higher.

Comment: A \$ \mu m=10^{-6}m \$ not \$10^{-9}m\$ used in the calculation.